# Usage of Hashset to initialize objects

Tags: list, properties, entity, hashset, icollection

I am in the learning curve of entity framework. I follow the tutorials in the entity framework in msdn. In the sample, entities are defined as follows;

```
public class Department 
{ 
    public Department() 
    { 
        this.Courses = new HashSet<Course>(); 
    } 
    // Primary key 
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public decimal Budget { get; set; } 
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; } 
    public int? Administrator { get; set; } 

    // Navigation property 
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; private set; } 
} 

public class Course 
{ 
    public Course() 
    { 
        this.Instructors = new HashSet<Instructor>(); 
    } 
    // Primary key 
    public int CourseID { get; set; } 

    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public int Credits { get; set; } 

    // Foreign key 
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; } 

    // Navigation properties 
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Instructor> Instructors { get; private set; } 
} 

public class Instructor 
{ 
    public Instructor() 
    { 
        this.Courses = new List<Course>(); 
    } 

    // Primary key 
    public int InstructorID { get; set; } 
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
    public string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public System.DateTime HireDate { get; set; } 

    // Navigation properties 
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; private set; } 
}
```

I only showed some of the classes focused on my question only. The full sample is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617). My doubt is 
**why they are used hashset in the constructor to create ICollection properties?**

hashset performance is good in the set operations If the hashset is appropriate in these type of areas, then

**why they initialized with List in the constuctor of 'Instructor' entity?**

May be simply shows the 2 options. But if not please advice and also tell me any other general scenarios to use hashset. Here they returnes as ICollection, only for initialization they used hashset.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they did this because a HashSet enforces uniqueness. So the courses for a department must be unique. But that may not be the case for an instructor